Scatter 3d animation frames dont display all traces
I have searched for proper animation script and come up with following function on how to add traces:
from plotly import graph_objects as go


def add_anim_frames(figure: go.Figure, traces):
    sliders_dict = {
        "active": 0,
        # "yanchor": "top",
        # "xanchor": "left",
        "currentvalue": {
            "font": {"size": 20},
            "prefix": "",
            "visible": True,
            "xanchor": "right"
        },
        "transition": {"duration": 300, "easing": "cubic-in-out"},
        "len": 0.9,
        # "x": 0.1,
        # "y": 0,
        "steps": [],
        'pad': dict(zip('lrtb', [0, 0, 0, 0])),

    }
    frames = [
        go.Frame(data=trace_list,
                 traces=list(range(len(trace_list))),
                 name=str(i))
        for i, trace_list in enumerate(traces)
    ]
    f_debug = frames[0]
    print(len(f_debug.data))
    print(f_debug.traces)

    sliders_dict['steps'] = [
        {"args": [[fr.name],
                  {"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": True},
                   "mode": "immediate",
                   "transition": {"duration": 0}}],
         "label": i,
         "method": "animate"} for i, fr in enumerate(frames)]

    figure.frames = frames
    figure.layout.updatemenus = [
        go.layout.Updatemenu(
            type='buttons',
            buttons=[
                go.layout.updatemenu.Button(
                    label="Play",
                    method="animate",
                    args=[
                        None,
                        {'frame': {"duration": 50, "redraw": True},
                         "mode": "immediate",
                         "fromcurrent": True,
                         "transition": {"duration": 50, "easing": "linear"}},
                    ]),
                go.layout.updatemenu.Button(
                    label='Pause',
                    method='animate',
                    args=[
                        [None],
                        {"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": False},
                         "mode": "immediate",
                         "transition": {"duration": 0}}
                    ]),
            ],
            bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', active=99, bordercolor='black',
            font=dict(size=11, color='white', ), showactive=False,
            **{
                "direction": "right",
                'pad': dict(zip('lrtb', [0, 0, 0, 0])),
                "x": 0.5,
                "xanchor": "right",
                "y": 1,
                "yanchor": "top"
            }
        ),

    ]
    figure.layout.sliders = [sliders_dict]

And i display my figure like this:
import numpy as np
from plotly import graph_objects as go


cube_points = np.zeros((8, 3))
cube_points[[2, 3, 4, 5], 0] = 1
cube_points[[1, 2, 5, 6], 1] = 1
cube_points[[4, 5, 6, 7], 2] = 1

N_FRAMES = 40
anim_points = np.stack([
    np.sin(np.arange(N_FRAMES)),
    np.cos(np.arange(N_FRAMES)),
    np.arange(N_FRAMES)/10
], axis=-1) 

static_traces = [
    go.Scatter3d(**dict(zip('xyz', cube_points.T*5)), mode='markers', name='static'),
    
]

anim_traces = [
    [
        go.Scatter3d(**dict(zip('xyz', anim_points[[i-1, i, i+1]].T + 2.5)), mode='lines', marker_color='lime'),
        go.Scatter3d(**dict(zip('xyz', anim_points[[i-1, i, i+1]].T + 2.7)), mode='lines', marker_color='olive'),
        go.Scatter3d(**dict(zip('xyz', anim_points[[i-1, i, i+1]].T+2.3)), mode='lines', marker_color='blue'),
    ]
    for i in range(1, N_FRAMES-1)]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d()])
fig.add_traces(static_traces)
fig.update_layout(plt.get_layout_3d(show_grid=True), height=700)
add_anim_frames(fig, anim_traces)
fig.show()

Problem is that it seems that Frame object is capable of displaying only 2 traces at once:
If i leave only 1 trace in anim traces list, static trace will be shown, if i will add extra enim trace, only anim traces will be shown and if i add even more, only first 2 anim traces will be shown. Please help

I found a dirty lifehack, you need to make placeholder traces in figure beforehand with number of traces displayed at once like this:
N_DISPLAYED = 4
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_traces([go.Scatter3d()]*N_DISPLAYED)


